# Store a specific column value until next value is identified

Tags: excel, vba

I have very basic knowledge in VBA, I have one requirement where the data for a specific set will be available in multiple rows and it will be like Header (ex. from A to D) and lines (ex. from E:J). Header will not be there for all the line rows, so when validating the line data with Header data, I need to validate the value in for ex. col "D2" with all the lines and when the new header is available, follow the same pattern again.

Below is the sample data format, in which col "A:D" represents Header data and from col "E:J" represents line data. Through out the line validation with Header, I want col "D" value to be captured through out that iteration.

[image]

Ex. When the "ABC" value is iterated, "PO1" should be available for validation for rows "E2:J4". After this iteration and when the new value on Col A, i.e "DEF" is encountered then the value in Col "D" to be changed like "PO2" from the next 2 rows of the Header.

As I have very basic knowledge in VB, not sure how I can achieve this. Can anyone help me here please?

I tried to compare the first value with the next available value in Col A, during this iteration tried storing the Col "D" value to a global variable but it is not giving me expected results

Sample code that i tried:

```
Public v As Integer

Sub inv()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, temp As Integer, rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Integer, lastRowSheet2 As Integer
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet

Set sheet1 = Sheets("Data")
Set Sheet2 = Sheets("res")
lrow = sheet1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row


For i = 2 To lrow
    
    If sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
        invv = sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value
        v = i

    End If
    If sheet1.Range("A" & i + 1).Value <> "" Then
        ninv = sheet1.Range("A" & i + 1).Value

    End If

    If invv <> ninv And sheet1.Range("A" & i + 1).Value <> "" Then
    
        Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value = sheet1.Range("D" & v).Value
        MsgBox "Alert -Entry in row is not equal to Previous Cell !!"
        
        'Exit Sub
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: post your trial code

Comment: Welcome hari krishna! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @user3598756, i have added the code in the original post

Answer (score 0):

... and what about filling in those values, like I did in this example:

1. Select all data (<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, Special, Current Region).
2. In there, select all blanks (<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, Special, Blanks).
3. Copy the value from the one above (<kbd>F2</kbd>, fill in `=A2`).
4. Fill in for all select (blank) cells (<kbd>**Ctrl**+ENTER</kbd>)

This is what you end up with:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Those cells will be left blank (in the actual scenario), if it is filled then there is no issue for me as per the logic the program will validate the value on the same row but the thing is for "ABC" Row 3 & 4 will be blank (based on number of lines). So looking for VB logic to point to "PO1" even when processing all the lines.

Comment: @harikrishna: are you saying that it is forbidden to fill in the values?

Comment: yes that data sheet should not have those values filled